# how to insert list of values into datatable in spring hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I need to insert multiple rows of values into same table at a single submit.[image]

In ajax

```
$("#btn_themDay").click(function(){
$("#themDay_validation").hide();
var no_row = Number($('#tbl_videoDetails').find("td.lastno").text());
var videoDetails_valid = true;
var name = new Array();
var land = new Array();
var area = new Array();
var District = new Array();
var thaluk = new Array();
var i;

for(i=1;i<=no_row;i++){     // validdation 
    name[i]=$("#vodtitle"+i).val();
    land[i]=$("#vodtime"+i).val();
    area[i]=$("#voduploadImage"+i).val();
    District[i]=$("#vodurl"+i).val();
    thaluk[i]=$("#voddes"+i).val();

$.ajax({
    url: "savefull",
    type: "POST",
    data: {values:name},
    traditional: true,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {

    }
});



return false;   // for testing return false
```

});

I catch the data in controller like this

```
    @RequestMapping(value="savefull",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ThematicDay savefull(@ModelAttribute("Data") Data values){
        try{
            System.out.print("Value "+values+"        ");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return null;

    }
```

But I don't know how to insert it in my dao using the hibernate query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Batch Inserts](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch15.html#batch-inserts)

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make a object which will be used for transferring the data in and out from db.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "data_table")   // let the table name be "data_table"
public class PData {
@Id
@Column(name = "data_id")
private String id;

@Column(name = "xyz")
private String xyz;

public PData() {
    // Initialize
}

write getter and setters
}
```

Then create a repository which will communicate with the db. You can use JPA Repository for handling it.

```
public interface DataRepository extends JpaRepository<PData, String> {
@Query("from PData where data_id = ?1")
List<PData> findByKey(String data_id);
}
```

For saving the Data create an object of **DataRepository** and call save method passing the **PData** Object;
For example:

```
DataRepository dr = new DataRepository();
PData pd = new PData();
pd.setName("xyz");
pd.setId(id);
//set all the values
dr.save(pd);
// then save to db
```